# Multiple foreign keys in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem while creating models. I have 3 models in my Rails application.

The first model is Event.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
    has_many :situations
end
```

Event model contains fields: `id, date, team`.

The second class is Items

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :situations
end
```

Item model contains fields: `event_id, ratio, kind, attr_1, attr_3` with data.

The third class is Situations

```
class Situations < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :items
end
```

Situation model contains fields: `event_id, first_item_id, second_item_id, third_item_id, percent`

I need to create 3 foreign keys (`first_item_id, second_item_id, third_item_id`), which will refer to primary key in Item model.

I have tried this code and then typed `Item.joins(:situations)` and so it doesn't work:

```
 class Item < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :event
   has_many :situations, class_name: 'Situation', foreign_key: ['first_item_id', 
    'second_item_id', 'third_item_id']
 end
```

## Update

For example:

```
  Situations table:

 id event_id first_item_id second_item_id third_item_id percent
  1   1001      2323           2324           2325         3%
  2   1001      2323           2525           2525


  Event table:

  id        date                  team
 1001   02/10/2019        'Chicago - New York'


 Item table:

  id    event_id  ratio    kind   attr_1   att_3
  2323    1001     2.3     test     12       15
  2323    1001     7.7     next     52       55
  2324    1001     8.7     nsext     5       18
  2325    1001     1.1     ext      4        58
```

and I want to get 2 big rows with data with all fields from event, item and situations table after executing Item.joins(:situations).

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about association, we have to define association for individual keys,

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
    has_many :first_for_situations, through: :items
    has_many :second_for_situations, through: :items
    has_many :third_for_situations, through: :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :first_for_situations, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :first_item_id
    has_many :second_for_situations, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :second_item_id
    has_many :third_for_situations, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :third_item_id
end

class Situation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :first_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :first_item_id
    belongs_to :second_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :second_item_id
    belongs_to :third_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: :third_item_id
end
```

If you want to get `ActiveRecord::Relation` object for multiple keys, use class method as below,

```
 class Item < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :event

   def situations
     where(first_item_id: id, second_item_id: id, third_item_id: id)
   end
 end
```

Comment: After I created these classes,I've tried to run  Event.joins(:items)/Event.join(:situations) it doesn't work too (issue `Can't join 'Situation' to association named 'events'; perhaps you misspelled it?`) As I wrote before I need to get data from items table and from event table and have one big row with data which I can display, that is why I need join I think

Comment: @Maksim I have updated answer little and know this, you can call as `Event.join(:first_for_situations)` as associations defined.

Comment: I'm getting another issue when used `Event.join(:first_for_situations)`, could you please have a look on this issue `LINE 1: ..."."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."fi...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "items" "items_events_join" ON "items_events_join"."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."first_item_id" = "items_events_join"."id" LIMIT $1`

Comment: I think this issue came because Item has no field first_item_id, because it shouldn't be on the table 'Item'

Comment: @Maksim I guess so, create database schema as you need and then create such kind of associations

Comment: I have already created tables in my database, I don't need any more fields there, just want to be done with my task